# Triangle inequality for complex function

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, normed-spaces

I have to prove triangle inequality for such function:
$f(z)=|z|+||\operatorname{Re}(z)|-|\operatorname{Im}(z)||$
so I want to prove:
$f(z+w) \le f(z)+f(w)$
Of course it can also be defined for real numbers:
$h(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+||x|-|y||$
however I don't see how would it help. I don't know anything about complex analysis that would be other than trigonometric or exponential form of complex number.
The problem is that:
$g(z) := ||\operatorname{Re}(z)|-\operatorname{Im}(z)||$ doesn't fulfill triangle inequality - $z=2+i $, $w=2-i$ - thus, modulus seems to be important.
I've run out of any ideas.
Btw. I need it to prove, that $h(x,y)$ is a norm.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, $f$ does *not* satisfy the triangle inequality for the same example $z=2+i$, $w=2-i$: $f(z) = f(w) = \sqrt 5 + 1 \approx 3.23$, $f(z+w) = f(4) = 8$.

Comment: Wow, sorry, I made some mistake doing calculation and my result was:
$f(z+w)=f(4)=5$ 
Thank You very much!